# How to fix pytest marker not picking up tests

Tags: python, pytest, markers, pytest-django, pytest-cov

I have my tests at src/com/xyz/tests/bla_tests/file1.py. I also have file2.py at that path.

I have the following code in file1.py

```
class HelloWorld():
    @pytest.mark.regressiontest
    def test_001_bla?():
        # Some code here.
```

From command line I invoke the test by :

```
pytest -v -m regressiontest but no items are collected. It says : collected 0 items.
```

My aim is to mark multiple tests across various files as regressiontest and be able to run them from the Command line. (On Mac).
The following command is able to collect the tests though

```
pytest -q file1.py -v -m regressiontest 

This says: collected 20 items / 11 deselected / 9 selected
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the resolution [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4340#issuecomment-436913257):

> pytest by default doesn't look for tests in files not named like
> test_*.py
>
> also using --basetemp=. actually does a rm -rf . so that's def not a
> good idea, we should warn about that

In my case, my file name was not starting from **test_***

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the pytest -v -m regressiontest , are you on your current folder tests ? 
I believe you should do `pytest src/com/xyz/tests/bla_tests/ -v -m regressiontest`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was inside the folder bla_tests when I was using pytest -v -m regressiontest to run the tests. I also tried the way you had mentioned and it still doesnt seem to work. Does the marker being in a test which is inside a class make any difference? Do I have to add something specific for the class?

Comment: How about changing the filenames to test_file1.py and test_file2.py . It might not get discovered. You can refer to this link for test discovery http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html

Comment: Tried changing it to test_file1_api.py and running it again. Still doesnt collect the tests. My class name also starts with test suffix. The interesting thing is pytest -q filename.py works. Its able to identify all the tests then. and pytest -q filename.py -v -m filename.py also works and it collects the tests accordingly. Problem arises when I dont have the file name mentioned. I basically want it to pick the tests across various files with the marker.

Comment: I have the same scenarios on my test suite but I never encounter this before. Maybe reading some docs will help.